# How to set dynamic Background Canvas Width in Fabricjs

Tags: fabricjs

How set dynamic Width of the canvas depending of the Image background resolution in **Fabricjs** Library.

It similar with the CSS image height: 100%; then the width will be dynamic and 500px height.

```
<canvas id="c" height="500" width="500"><canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Here according to canvas you can set image width and height.

  ```js
  const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");

   fabric.Image.fromURL('https://www.kraftwerk.at/app/uploads/fly-images/962/reference-img-worlds-of-adventure-park-4-1920x9999.jpg', function(img) {
                      canvas.setBackgroundImage(img, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
                          scaleX: 200,
                          scaleY: canvas.height / img.height
                      });
                  });
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/460/fabric.min.js"></script>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="450" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
  ```